# How can I execute a class level decorator for a class that isn't used directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have the following class:

```py
@jsonpickle.handlers.register(Enum, base=True)
class EnumHandler(BaseHandler):
   ... snip ...
```

When the decorator is executed, it registers the class with `jsonpickle` and is then used whenever it needs to serialize/deserialize an Enum.

My code never class `EnumHandler` directly. Therefore, I believe the class is never initialized and the decorator is never executed.

If I add an arbitrary import for `EnumHandler` in another file that is used, then everything works. However, I don't like this because `EnumHandler` isn't used by that file so the import appears to be redundant. My IDE (PyCharm) marks it as unused and another developer could easily remove it without realizing they are breaking functionality.

Is there a better way to ensure this class is initialized?

Comment: Python code won't magically run if you don't run/import the module. This is the same for *anything* regardless of the class. What exactly is the struture of your project? You could probably put the import in an appropriate `__init__.py`

Comment: Why don't you just put the class definition in some module that is always run?